# Layer Tree Collapse Alongside OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, list

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/748gnfyj/3/) that includes a layer tree for my OpenLayers3 map.

It is currently set up so that when you click on the branch 'parent', the layers collapse. I'm looking to make it so that on the page load, the "Cities" and Background Mapping" 'parents' are collapsed and the user can choose which branch they expand.

Preferably I wouldn't like it to collapse all the way up to "All Layers". As per the comments below, Twitter Bootstrap may be used.

Comment: You include twitter-bootstrap already. So my suggestion you try it with the Collapse-plugin: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example and set the class `collapse` for the root.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelJS, i get this, just unsure where exactly the `collapse` tag goes?

Comment: @MichaelJS would the collapse tag go into the section where the layer tree is being built? Thanks

Comment: See the example on getbootstrap. The Element which should be displayed/visible by default got the classes  "collapse in". So on your example you need to add this to the direct child of the base-layer (first <ul>-Element i think) . The childs of Cities and Background-Mapping should'nt be visible then. But do get to this you need to add ssome logic in your tree-building mechanism beacuse I think its looping through all the layers with the same "template".